# Invalid allocation size error in pcl1.7.2

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, kinect-sdk, point-cloud-library

I try to display aligned rgb point clouds using icp algorithm.But during alignment of point cloud it throws "Invalid allocation size error".

My code:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr PassingCloudstoICP( pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointCloud1, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointCloud2) 
        {   
                pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB> icp; 
                icp.setInputCloud (pointCloud1); 
                 icp.setInputTarget (pointCloud2); 
                // Set the max correspondence distance to 5cm (e.g., correspondences with higher distances will be ignored) 
                icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05); 
                //Set the maximum number of iterations (criterion 1) 
                icp.setMaximumIterations (25); 
                // Set the transformation epsilon (criterion 2) 
                icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-8); 
                // Set the euclidean distance difference epsilon (criterion 3) 
                icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1); 
                //Perform the alignment 
                icp.align(*finalcloud); 
                return finalcloud; 
        }
```

I have tried to debug it and done code walkthrough,when icp.align(*finalcloud) executes it goes to the following file registration.hpp,here it goes through following 
function.

```
--- pcl::Registration<PointSource, PointTarget, Scalar>::align (PointCloudSource &output, const Matrix4& guess)"

     --- "initcompute()"

     ---- "setInputCloud(target_)" -- when this line executes the compiler throws "Invalid allocation size 4294967295 bytes"
```

Please suggest me how to fix this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're on a 32 bit system and are trying to allocate a huge amount of memory, is this correct? You're hitting the limit of a 32 bit size_t so it can't give you the amount of space you're asking for. This could be caused by a bug in your code passing a negative value as a size parameter?

Comment: Thanks, I am using visual studio2012 with win32 configuration with 64 bit system.

Comment: Is there any chance a negative number is being passed as a size, or are you trying to make huge objects (do you know the matrix dimensions)?

Comment: I am getting the 1920 *  1080 resolution of rgb data and depth data of 512 * 424 resolution from kinect sensor 1 as "Pointcloud1" and same resolution of rgb and depth data from kinect sensor 2 and passing to the above ICP function.The pointcloud1 and pointcloud2 are 3D points which will have negative numbers also.

So obviously it is big data.Please suggest me whether big data will also leads to "Invalid allocation size error".